# Does $ \int_{\Omega} |f|g \mathrm{d} x \geq \| f \|_{L^1(\Omega)} (\operatorname{ess} \inf g) $ hold?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

**Background:** Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain, $f,g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, with $f \in L^{1}(\Omega)$, $g \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. By Holder inequality, $fg \in L^1(\Omega)$ and
$$ \| fg \|_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq \| f \|_{L^{1}(\Omega} \| g \|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}.$$
with $\|g\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} = \operatorname{ess} \sup |g|$.

In [*Sobolev Spaces*, Adams] [page 27, theorem 2.12](https://books.google.com/books?id=R5A65Koh-EoC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA27#v=onepage&q&f=false) (**Reverse Holder Inequality**),
$$ \| fg \|_{L^1(\Omega)} \geq \| f \|_{L^p(\Omega)} \| g \|_{L^q(\Omega)}$$
with $0 < p < 1$ and $p^{-1} + q^{-1} = 1$.

**Question 1:** Can I conclude in the limit $p \to 1^{-}$ and $ q \to -\infty$ that,

$$ \| fg \|_{L^1(\Omega)} \geq  \| f \|_{L^1(\Omega)} (\operatorname{ess} \inf g) $$
holds?

**Question 2:** Does the following

$$ \int_{\Omega} |f| g ~\mathrm{d} x \geq  \| f \|_{L^1(\Omega)} (\operatorname{ess} \inf g)  $$

also hold? Intuitively it should make sense since the set $\{ x \in \Omega ~|~ g(x) < \operatorname{ess} \inf g \}$ is Lebesgue measure zero. But I want to be careful if I am missing any extra condition.

Comment: What if $f\le 0$?

Comment: I modified the question with $|f|$.

Comment: Then it is true, because the inequality (of functions) $|f|g\ge |f|\text{ess inf}\ g$ holds a.e. So $\int_\Omega |f|gd x \ge \int_\Omega |f|\text{ess inf}\ g=\|f\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\text{ess inf}\ g$.